# Как вывести каналов на Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Написал небольшой клиент на Qt. У клиента есть несколько комнат-каналов. Как на виджетах можно в в окошко вывести список этих каналов, к которым клиент подключен, с возможность зайти в них?

Comment: QListView / QListWidget? А что за комнаты-каналы?

Comment: канал - обычное окно с выводом текста от сервера. хочу сделать окошко, в котором отображаются все каналы (+ метка, есть или нет новые сообщения), и чтобы можно было зайти в эти каналы.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html